# Warming Up Cache Digests Overnight

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cron, memcached, cache-digests

We have a Rails 3.2 website which is fairly large with thousands of URLs. We implemented Cache_Digests gem for Russian Doll caching. It is working well. We want to further optimize by warming up the cache overnight so that user gets a better experience during the day. I have seen answer to this question: [Rails: Scheduled task to warm up the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282811/rails-scheduled-task-to-warm-up-the-cache)

Could it be modified for warming up large number of URLs?

Answer (score 2):

To **trigger cache hits for many pages** with expensive load times, just create a rake task to iteratively send web requests to all record/url combinations within your site. ([Here is one implementation](https://github.com/warneboldt/frasernw/blob/master/lib/tasks/visit_every_page.rake))

### Iteratively `Net::HTTP` request all site URL/records:

To only visit every page, you can run a nightly Rake task to make sure that early morning users still have a snappy page with refreshed content.

*lib/tasks/visit_every_page.rake*:

```
namespace :visit_every_page do
  include Net
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  task :specializations => :environment do
    puts "Visiting specializations..."
    Specialization.all.sort{ |a,b| a.id <=> b.id }.each do |s|
      begin
        puts "Specialization #{s.id}"
        
        City.all.sort{ |a,b| a.id <=> b.id }.each do |c|
          puts "Specialization City #{c.id}"
          Net::HTTP.get( URI("http://#{APP_CONFIG[:domain]}/specialties/#{s.id}/#{s.token}/refresh_city_cache/#{c.id}.js") )
        end
      
        Division.all.sort{ |a,b| a.id <=> b.id }.each do |d|
          puts "Specialization Division #{d.id}"
          Net::HTTP.get( URI("http://#{APP_CONFIG[:domain]}/specialties/#{s.id}/#{s.token}/refresh_division_cache/#{d.id}.js") )
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # The following methods are defined to fake out the ActionController
  # requirements of the Rails cache
  
  def cache_store
    ActionController::Base.cache_store
  end

  def self.benchmark( *params )
    yield
  end

  def cache_configured?
    true
  end
end
```

[(If you want to directly include cache expiration/recaching into this task, check out this implementation.)](https://github.com/warneboldt/frasernw/blob/master/lib/tasks/recache.rake)

### via a Custom Controller Action:

If you need to bypass user authentication restrictions to get to your pages, and/or you don't want to screw up (too badly) your website's tracking analytics, you can create a [custom controller action](https://github.com/warneboldt/frasernw/blob/587033cd33d872f06e7e5997d451a7d06458f86d/app/controllers/specializations_controller.rb#L105-L109) for hitting cache digests that [use tokens to bypass authentication](https://github.com/warneboldt/frasernw/blob/587033cd33d872f06e7e5997d451a7d06458f86d/app/controllers/specializations_controller.rb#L4-L5):

*app/controllers/specializations.rb:*

```
class SpecializationsController < ApplicationController
...
  before_filter :check_token, :only => [:refresh_cache, :refresh_city_cache, :refresh_division_cache]
  skip_authorization_check :only => [:refresh_cache, :refresh_city_cache, :refresh_division_cache]

...

  def refresh_cache
    @specialization = Specialization.find(params[:id])
    @feedback = FeedbackItem.new
    render :show, :layout => 'ajax'
  end

  def refresh_city_cache
    @specialization = Specialization.find(params[:id])
    @city = City.find(params[:city_id])
    render 'refresh_city.js'
  end

  def refresh_division_cache
    @specialization = Specialization.find(params[:id])
    @division = Division.find(params[:division_id])
    render 'refresh_division.js'
  end

end
```

Our custom controller action renders the views of other expensive to load pages, causing cache hits to those pages.  E.g. *`refresh_cache`* renders the same view page & data as *controller#show*, so requests to *`refresh_cache`* will warm up the same cache digests as *controller#show* for those records.

### Security Note:

For security reasons, I recommend before providing access to any custom `refresh_cache` controller request that you pass in a token [and check it](https://github.com/warneboldt/frasernw/blob/27f8e9f5af57b4ba1f48a622c86d6bc9943ba586/app/controllers/specializations_controller.rb#L95-L97) to make sure that [it corresponds with a unique token for that record.](https://github.com/warneboldt/frasernw/blob/585ade682ec3acc0b56543abc49b48d42720829f/lib/controller_authentication.rb#L72-L77) Matching URL tokens to database records before providing access (as seen above) is trivial because your Rake task has access to the unique tokens of each record -- just pass the record's token in with each request.

### **tl;dr:**

To trigger thousands of site URL's/cache digests, create a rake task to iteratively request every record/url combination in your site.  You can bypass your app's user authentication restrictions for this task by creating a a custom controller action that authenticates access via tokens instead.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is about a year old, but I just worked out my own answer, after scouring a bunch of partial & incorrect solutions.

Hopefully this will help the next person...

Per my own utility class, which can be found here: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JayTeeSF/cmd_notes/master/automated_action_runner.rb

You can simply run this (per it's .help method) and pre-cache your pages, without tying-up your own web-server, in the process.

```
class AutomatedActionRunner  
  class StatusObject
    def initialize(is_valid, error_obj)
      @is_valid = !! is_valid
      @error_obj = error_obj
    end

    def valid?
      @is_valid
    end

    def error
      @error_obj
    end
  end

  def self.help
    puts <<-EOH
      Instead tying-up the frontend of your production site with:
        `curl http://your_production_site.com/some_controller/some_action/1234`
        `curl http://your_production_site.com/some_controller/some_action/4567`
      Try:
        `rails r 'AutomatedActionRunner.run(SomeController, "some_action", [{id: "1234"}, {id: "4567"}])'`
    EOH
  end

  def self.common_env
    {"rack.input"  => "", "SCRIPT_NAME" => "", "HTTP_HOST" => "localhost:3000" }
  end
  REQUEST_ENV = common_env.freeze

  def self.run(controller, controller_action, params_ary=[], user_obj=nil)
    success_objects = []
    error_objects = []
    autorunner = new(controller, controller_action, user_obj)
    Rails.logger.warn %Q|[AutomatedAction Kickoff]: Preheating cache for #{params_ary.size} #{autorunner.controller.name}##{controller_action} pages.|

    params_ary.each do |params_hash|
      status = autorunner.run(params_hash)
      if status.valid?
        success_objects << params_hash
      else
        error_objects << status.error
      end
    end

    return process_results(success_objects, error_objects, user_obj.try(:id), autorunner.controller.name, controller_action)
  end

  def self.process_results(success_objects=[], error_objects=[], user_id, controller_name, controller_action)
    message = %Q|AutomatedAction Summary|
    backtrace = (error_objects.first.try(:backtrace)||[]).join("\n\t").inspect
    num_errors = error_objects.size
    num_successes = success_objects.size

    log_message = %Q|[#{message}]: Generated #{num_successes} #{controller_name}##{controller_action}, pages; Failed #{num_errors} times; 1st Fail: #{backtrace}|
    Rails.logger.warn log_message

    # all the local-variables above, are because I typically call Sentry or something with extra parameters!
  end

  attr_reader :controller
  def initialize(controller, controller_action, user_obj)
    @controller = controller
    @controller = controller.constantize unless controller.respond_to?(:name)
    @controller_instance = @controller.new
    @controller_action = controller_action
    @env_obj = REQUEST_ENV.dup
    @user_obj = user_obj
  end

  def run(params_hash)
    Rails.logger.warn %Q|[AutomatedAction]: #{@controller.name}##{@controller_action}(#{params_hash.inspect})|
    extend_with_autorun unless @controller_instance.respond_to?(:autorun)

    @controller_instance.autorun(@controller_action, params_hash, @env_obj, @user_obj)
  end


  private

  def extend_with_autorun
    def @controller_instance.autorun(action_name, action_params, action_env, current_user_value=nil)
      self.params = action_params # suppress strong parameters exception
      self.request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(action_env)
      self.response = ActionDispatch::Response.new
      define_singleton_method(:current_user, -> { current_user_value })

      send(action_name) # do it
      return StatusObject.new(true, nil)
    rescue Exception => e
      return StatusObject.new(false, e)
    end
  end
end
```